# Is this called a water tank or a tank of water? Or both are idiomatic?

Tags: word-usage

Is this called a water tank or a tank of water? Or both are idiomatic?

[image]

Comment: A _water tank_ is a tank intended to hold water, whether or not it has water in it now. The one in the photo could be described either way.

Comment: @KateBunting So, both of them are idiomatic, right?

Comment: Yes, I would have told you if one of them was not.